# How to integrate PS3 & Xbox 360 games to Facebook?

Tags: facebook, xbox360, playstation3

After some research online, I am unable to find any concrete references for how to go about implementing Facebook functionality from either Xbox 360 or PS3 games.  There is apparently some degree of integration, but how does one go about hooking into Facebook's API from within a console title?

Is there any How To documentation online?  Or alternatively, is anyone aware of a developer that specializes in incorporating this type of functionality in an existing codebase?

For an answer unaffected by NDA, does anyone know of a company that specializes in integrating PS3 or Xbox games with Facebook?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if you can do that on the Xbox if your just using XNA. I thought the only way to communicate over the net would be to use their network API. Maybe you could have a server that would connect to facebook for your clients. I don't know about their actual XDK.

Comment: I don't believe this question can be answered without breaching the NDA terms for either PS3 or X360. Which is probably why you can't find anything concrete online. If you could, those behind it could be struck off as licenced developers

Comment: Indeed, the way you'd do this on an Xbox would be to set up an XLSP server that mirrors requests from the player to Facebook and back. I probably can't say more than that.

Comment: It'd be really neat to have nice, extensive facebook integration.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it directly. We moved it so all the API interaction was done server-side so it was post-gateway. Made screenshots a real pain actually. You could have some limited interaction if your Facebook app just watched for changes in their Live profile, not sure if you can get stuff like the rich presence data that way though.

Comment: Was this for standard Xbox 360 games, or for XNA, Xbox Live games?  Thanks for the info!

Comment: Standard 360 game. XNA games are never allowed to talk to anything other than other copies of that game no matter what (figured that was understood as a given).